# jQuery not working with simple code

Tags: jquery

I can´t understand why jquery dosent work on this simple line of code.

i have script tags in head:

```
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p>jQuery will hide this :)</p>

</body>
```

And this is my script.js

```
$(function(){

$('p').hide(400);


});
```

Also in my console i get this erroe:
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$(function(){

What is wrong??

Comment: are you working on a file system e.g. windows or do you use a server such as apache?

Comment: no server.this is just localy on my macbook

Comment: instead of using "$", use jQuery - lets see if that does it. I know it doesn't solve your overall issue of using "$", but lets see if the reference is bunked. Also, what is in script.js -- perhaps something in there is over-writing the "$" representation.

Comment: Your browser is bloking remote access to files served from the file:// protocol. Download the jQuery file to your local directory, and change the src to be the file name.

Answer (score 2):

Your Solution:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

The problem is that it will open it as file:// ... and will prepend that to it!

`<script src="file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score -3):

I solved it.
Just changed the script to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does solve the problem, but this does not address the problem, which is that you didn't specify to use the `http` protocol. (You were using the `file` protocol.)